# Android ImageView between ImageButtons

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageButton at either end and an ImageView in the middle.  I want the ImageButtons to be the default android size with the ImageView using all the remaining space in the center.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@drawable/left" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBoard"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@drawable/right" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the ImageButtons first and then set the ImageView between them by using `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRight"` and `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnLeft"`

This will work for you:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRight"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnLeft"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```